# *ngFor over not yet existing data structure

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ngfor

**EDIT:

Its not strange that it wasn't working. the *ngFor of the organizations is closed before I access it in the next ion-group, closing everything later on in the code solved my issue.**

I am working on a Ionic2 app which uses angular2. After a succesfull login I change to the next view. On load of the next view I do a GET request which sends me an array of objects.

In my old app created in Ionic1 (angular 1) I was able to write the html file, based on the objects I was about to receive. And it wouldnt render until the data was received.

After my new struggles with Ionic2 last night it seems that whenever I have a *ngFor over a undefined variable it wont load. Due to a property not being able to be found.

Code for context:

```
<ion-item-group>                                                            
    <ion-item *ngFor="let organization of organizations"                    
        (click)="toggleDetails(organization)">                              
        <ion-icon item-left name="add">                                     
        </ion-icon>                                                         
        {{organization.Name}}                                               
    </ion-item>                                                             
    <ion-item-group>        
        <ion-item-divider *ngFor="let Assignment of organization.Assignments">                                         
            {{assignmentNameMaker(Assignment)}}                             
        </ion-item-divider>                                                 
    </ion-item-group>
```

I did not have the problem with the first ngFor, but that's cause an empty array organizations was created upon the load. I tried the `? elvis operator`. Eventhough the first part got loaded, I didn't see any of the dividers being loaded. (also tried just putting in something like "lalalal")

**EDIT:

Its not strange that it wasn't working. the *ngFor of the organizations is closed before I access it in the next ion-group, closing everything later on in the code solved my issue.**

Comment: You can also use the `async` pipe with `*ngFor`. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html

Answer (score 3):

Just add the field to your component and then later assign a value:

```
class MyComponent {
  organizations:any[];

}
```

`*ngFor` doesn't care if the field has a value. When later a value is assigned or the content changes, `*ngFor` updates the DOM accordingly.

Comment: _"an empty array organizations was created upon the load"_ ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use below code it automatically exclude the element when "organization" is empty.

```
*ngIf="organization"
```

Comment: You can't have more than one structural directive on a single tag. You would need to split `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` to two tags.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I agree with you  that we cannot follow this structure thus I edited my answer. Although we can use this directive to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `?` operator for null safe check as follows.

```
    <ion-item-divider *ngFor="let Assignment of organization?.Assignments">
        {{assignmentNameMaker(Assignment)}}
    </ion-item-divider>
```

Look at `?` marks used in `ngFor` as `organization?.Assignments`

Comment: Though I believe @Günter Zöchbauer solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyComponent {
  organizations:any[] = null; 
}

<ion-item-group *ngIf="organizations">                                                            
    <ion-item *ngFor="let organization of organizations"                    
        (click)="toggleDetails(organization)">                              
        <ion-icon item-left name="add">                                     
        </ion-icon>                                                         
        {{organization.Name}}                                               
    </ion-item>                                                             
    <ion-item-group>        
        <ion-item-divider *ngFor="let Assignment of organization.Assignments">                                         
            {{assignmentNameMaker(Assignment)}}                             
        </ion-item-divider>                                                 
    </ion-item-group>
```